# How to get background logger class to finish logging when application exits. (C# multi-threading)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, logging

I am  new to C# programming and just for  learning's sake I wanted to make an asynchronous application logger that runs on a low priority background thread. I have written a logger class that serves as an interface for any other class in the application to make new log entries. This  logger then simply sends it to a log dispatcher, which then pushes it to a BlockingCollection< Log >, from which a loop continuously tries to take a log from and write to the logfile on a background thread.

HOWEVER, The problem I am having is that if the application requests a log entry just before it exits, the logs are never written. The Dispose method of the LogDispatcher is also never called as the exit log in the method is never written. I am not sure how to make the background thread finish going through the entire blocking collection before it terminates and then call the dispose method when the parent application thread terminates. Here is the code.

```
 public sealed class Logger : ILogger
 {
    // Fully lazy implementation for 
    // 1) learning purposes and
    // 2) in case log disabling is a feature to be added in the future
    private static readonly Lazy<Logger> L = new Lazy<Logger>(() => new Logger());

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return L.Value;
        }
    }

    private double entryNumber = 0;
    private int verbosity { get; set; }`private Logger()
    {
        this.verbosity = 3;
        LogDispatcher.Instance.pushNewLog(new Log(
            Log.LogType.Debug,
            entryNumber++,
            "LOG -- LogFile created with verbosity " + this.verbosity,
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy - mm - dd hh: mm:ss.fff")));
    }

    public void debug(string message)
    {
        if (this.verbosity > 2)
        {
            LogDispatcher.Instance.pushNewLog(new Log(
                Log.LogType.Debug,
                entryNumber++,
                message,
                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"
            )));
        }
    }

    public void warning(string warning)
    {
        if (this.verbosity > 1)
        {
            LogDispatcher.Instance.pushNewLog(new Log(
                Log.LogType.Warning,
                entryNumber++,
                warning,
                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"
            )));
        }
    }

    public void exception(string message, Exception e)
    {
        LogDispatcher.Instance.pushNewLog(new Log(
            Log.LogType.Exception,
            (entryNumber++),
            message,
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"),
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            e
        ));
    }
```

The code for the dispatcher is as follows

```
internal class LogDispatcher : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Lazy<LogDispatcher> LD = new Lazy<LogDispatcher>(() => new LogDispatcher());

    private readonly StreamWriter LogFile;

    private readonly BlockingCollection<Log> logQueue;

    private Thread loggingThread;

    private bool terminate = false;

    public static LogDispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return LD.Value;
        }
    }private LogDispatcher()
    {
        // initialize the log folder
        string logPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\NETLogger";
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while making the logfile.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        // now make logfile
        try
        {
            this.LogFile = File.CreateText(logPath + "\\LogFile.txt");
            this.LogFile.AutoFlush = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured while opening LogFile.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        // make the blocking collection that stores all queued logs
        this.logQueue = new BlockingCollection<Log>();

        // initialize writer loggingThread to run in the background
        this.loggingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(logWriter));
        this.loggingThread.IsBackground = true;
        this.loggingThread.Start();
    }

    public void logWriter()
    {
        Log writingLog = new Log();
        while (!terminate && logQueue.Count != 0)
        {
            if (this.logQueue.TryTake(out writingLog, -1))
            {
                switch(writingLog.lType)
                {
                    case (Log.LogType.Debug) :
                        LogFile.WriteLine(writingLog.entryNumber + " -- DEBUG -- " + writingLog.timeStamp);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t" + writingLog.message);
                        break;

                    case (Log.LogType.Warning) :
                        LogFile.WriteLine(writingLog.entryNumber + " -- WARNING -- " + writingLog.timeStamp);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t" + writingLog.message);
                        break;

                    case (Log.LogType.Exception) :
                        LogFile.WriteLine(writingLog.entryNumber + " -- EXCEPTION -- " + writingLog.timeStamp);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t ============== EXCEPTION INFORMATION FOLLOWS ============== ");
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t Log Message : " + writingLog.message);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t Exception Message: " + writingLog.e.Message);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t Exception Thread :" + writingLog.threadId);
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t Source: " + writingLog.e.ToString());
                        LogFile.WriteLine("\t=============== END EXCEPTION INFORMATION ================== ");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   public void pushNewLog(Log log)
    {
        logQueue.Add(log);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.logQueue.Add(new Log(
            Log.LogType.Debug,
            -1,
            "Terminating All Logging Procedures",
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff")));
        this.logQueue.CompleteAdding();
        this.terminate = true;
        this.loggingThread.Join();
    }

    ~LogDispatcher()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `Thread.Join` method or mark your thread as a foreground thread by setting `IsBackground = false;`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx):

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

I know you are probably learning threads but if that is not the case then use the higher abstraction so you do not have to deal with threads directly. Use `Task` like this:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomethingElse());
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
```

**EDIT**

In the comment the OP asked: why the dispose method is not called when the distructor for the dispatcher is called?

It is not called because you need to call it. See below pattern for how to do this.

```
public class ComplexResourceHolder : IDisposable
{

    private IntPtr buffer; // unmanaged memory buffer
    private SafeHandle resource; // disposable handle to a resource

    public ComplexResourceHolder()
    {
        this.buffer = ... // allocates memory
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    // disposing will be false when it is called from the finalize. 
    // I remember this by telling myself: "finalize has 'f' in it 
    // and false has 'f' in it so disposing is false when called by finalizer".
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory
        if (disposing)
        { // release other disposable objects
            if (resource != null) resource.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~ComplexResourceHolder()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

> X AVOID making types finalizable.
>   Carefully consider any case in which you think a finalizer is needed. There is a real cost associated with instances with finalizers, from both a performance and code complexity standpoint. Prefer using resource wrappers such as SafeHandle to encapsulate unmanaged resources where possible, in which case a finalizer becomes unnecessary because the wrapper is responsible for its own resource cleanup.
>
> X DO NOT make value types finalizable.
>   Only reference types actually get finalized by the CLR, and thus any attempt to place a finalizer on a value type will be ignored. The C# and C++ compilers enforce this rule.
>
> ✓ DO make a type finalizable if the type is responsible for releasing an unmanaged resource that does not have its own finalizer.

Comment: `IsBackground = false`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes I am trying to learn threading, ergo the manual thread management. My followup question is, if a make the thread a foreground thread, will it be the same trhead as the one the main application is running on. Will it slow down the other processes and make the program wait until the logs have finished writing?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Could you also tell me why the dispose method is not called when the distructor for the dispatcher is called? Is it because of the thread being background and terminating prematurely?

Comment: @Vector making a thread foreground thread is still a thread. No it is not the same as the main thread. The destructor does not call your Dispose method because you are not calling it. See edit please.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks again. Last question. Is it better in this case to make the dispatcher implement IDisposable or should l just make a final exit log entry within the distructor and let GC manually distruct the class when the thread ends, since this will reduce code complexity.

Comment: I don't think you get my point. Why do you have a destructor?

Comment: @CodingYoshi So to  explain my question in detail: I want the  logger  to  log a message that log is ending when  the program  exits. How do i make that happen? And even after switching the  thread  to a foreground one, sometimes the logger does not write all the log messages before the application exits. I am using Task.Factory.StartNew to execute the write loop now.